# Running a function without old values

Tags: javascript

I want to rerun a function if it returns true and rerun it after a second if it returns false.

```
function longSynchronous() {
  return condition ? true : false // "condition" is a longlasting synchronous request which either returns true or false
}
function schedule() {
  if (longSynchronous()) {
     schedule()
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
       schedule()
    }, 1000);
  }
}
schedule()
```

However, after one round, `longSynchronous()` already equals true or false without having to run and complete again. So I end up having infinitely running function `schedule()` without ever stopping for timeout.
Is there a way to make `schedule()` run each time without being `true` or `false`

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 - it's already posted.

Comment: Can you share what your `condition` looks like?

Comment: It's hard to say without a fiddle example, but it sounds like the problem is not ```longSynchronous()``` but ```condition```. ```longSynchronous()``` isn't a variable, so each time it's called is a _new_ call. ```condition```, on the other hand, could be anything.

So... what's in ```condition```?

Comment: If you get an infinite recursion that means condition is always truthy. You will have to post the code of `condition`.

Comment: It looks like I indeed always get truthy condition. Thank to all of you for helping me recognize the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to poll for something but your program isn't waiting for the poll result each time. If that's the case, then callbacks will help you here.

```
function longSynchronous(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(condition);
  });
}
function schedule() {
  longSynchronous(function(result) {
    if(result) {
      schedule()
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        schedule()
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
}
schedule()
```

[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating that functionality, but I'm a bit confused by the last part of your question so I could be off the mark here.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy there is some problem in your condition, because in your if condition you are calling longSynchronous() which is a function and on every call it will return a value according to your condition and not a variable which is meant to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at sample below, it has a promise version, and callback version, even though you func is sync, that should help you to get things done

```js
//promise version
function longSynchronous() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //true or false
    resolve(Math.random() > .5);
  });
}

function schedule() {
  //consume promise result
  longSynchronous().then(function(value) {
    if (value) {
      //simple logger
      print(0);
      schedule();
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        print(1000);
        schedule();
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
}
schedule();

//node style version
//promise version
function longSynchronous(callback) {
  callback(null, Math.random() > .5);
}

function schedule() {
  //call with callback
  longSynchronous(function(err, value) {
    if (value) {
      print(0);
      schedule();
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        print(1000);
        schedule();
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
}
schedule();

function print(num){
  var ul =  document.querySelector('ul');
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = num;
  ul.appendChild(li);
  
}
```

```html
<p>Note that 1000 appear as sequence, while 0 appears instantly</p>
<ul></ul>
```